# Can i use UIPageViewControllers at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I want to show 2 books at the same time.(for iPad)
Can i use UIPageViewControllers for this?

Comment: I tried to build UIPageViewController Sample. I can use a book in this program. but 2 books is not.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, you can, as long as each book is contained in it's own view.